# MySQL slow queries

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 6098369 records in it and growing.
The queries are really slow and I was wondering if you have any tips for my situation.

Here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE  `sametime`.`message` (
  `messageID` int(100) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `userFrom` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userTo` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `msg` varchar(65000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `conversationID` int(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`messageID`),
  KEY `userFromIndex` (`userFrom`(5)),
  KEY `userToIndex` (`userTo`(5)),
  KEY `timestampIndex` (`timestamp`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6098370 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see I have added indexes with hopes of that working.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL's EXPLAIN?

Comment: Can you provide specific queries that are slow and their explain plans?

Comment: We need to see the query which is slow

Comment: As everyone else has said, you need to provide the query and the explain before anyone can really help.  That said, do you happen to have the username in a different table because the userFrom / userTo are VARCHAR fields anything going against those will be slower than if they were INTs so changing that could improve the speed of your query (after restructuring the rest of the information).

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing your select statements it's clear that searching this table on VARCHAR usernames is going to be much slower than searching on an integer indexed field.
You should consider moving usernames to a seperate table and having a userNo foreign key in this table.

Also, no index on the conversationID? Wouldn't that be a key lookup field?

Other than that as mentioned by ceejayoz MySQL's EXPLAIN statement should be your first avenue.

Comment: +1, also the table has some inconsistencies (`conversationID INT(100)` isn't really.. good). An overindexed table with bad index choices will be slow. Also, what's the InnoDB configuration? 6 mil records on such a small table shouldn't cause huge problems.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual queries that are slow...

Try using [compound index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) on `UserFrom,Timestamp` and `UserTo,Timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

Without specific queries and EXPLAIN output not much can be said. However I would change `msg` from `VARCHAR(650000`) to `TEXT` because for each row that MySQL puts into memory whole 65000 bytes are allocated.

Also I'm curious - why You use `INT(100)`? It does not allow You to store `2^100` values in it, just `2^32` as regular `INT` do. `INT(100)` differs only in display options AFAIR.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think I figured out my main issue. The main reason it was slow was that I didn't setup the conversationID as a foreign key.  I also took the other suggestions about the table design.
Thanks for the responses